# VSCode C# with portable dotnet binaries

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code, portability

Is it possible to use VSCode with .Net Core SDK being portable and if so, how? (Instead of installing it, I want to keep the dotnet folder inside my portable VSCode directory and use it without defining any enviroment variable)

Comment: You mean you want to use the sdk without installing it? Probably no. Or you want to publish the application and use it on computers without dotnet installed? That is possible with self-contained publish. But I think you need to clarify or reword the question.

Comment: I meant to say that I wanted to use the sdk without installing it.